# TFS InvokeMethod Delete Access to the path is denied

Tags: file, tfs, unc

I am trying to call invokemethod to delete a file in the drop folder. However I am receiving access to the path is denied message. I am also doing copydirectories and delete directory before using invokmethod. Both copy and delete directories work with no permission issue.
I am guessing invokemethod use different user account. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default the build agent runs with the build service account of Network Service. You may want to change it to a domain account such as [TFSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253149.aspx) so you could assign write permissions on the paths you need your build artifacts.

Then make sure *TFSBuild* is running the build service and is a member of the [Project Collection Build Service Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668757.aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will also get access denied error, when you have the file in use.